# How to get column name of table from Db1 when query is executed in DB2

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have two database `DB1` and `DB2`. `DB1` have a table named `table1`. I have a `Stored Procedure` in `DB2` where I will execute this query

`select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='table1'`

but I get nothing in return. How can I do this? I tried adding the database name but failed.

Comment: is this Postgres? SQL Server? Knowing which database is vital to answering, don't skip this when tagging you questions please. "sql" a standardized query language (*& isn't a synonym of "sql server"*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below query:

```
Select COLUMN_NAME from DB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='table1'
```

Comment: yea i just found it too.

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia hey bro! if it really helps, then you should accept it. I'll also vote up your question.

Comment: Okay bro. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia Thank you too. I'm also voting up your question so that you can get some reputation and also others can get help from it. Please don't try to unaccept it again. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't unaccept your answer :). I just forgot to accept your answer

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia Thanks. I just said this so that you don't try to do that in future please.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer.I just lack some code

`select column_name from Database_Name.information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'Table_Name' AND table_schema = 'dbo'`